# Need to use multiple algorithm inside single figure having subcaptions for each algorithm

Tags: subfloats, algorithms, algorithm2e

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove \EndIf
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{$Game PrvInd_{G,\phi}$}
\label{pseudoPSO}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{Garble}{$f_0, f_1, x_0, x_1$} 

    \If{$f(\phi(f0) \neq\phi(f1)$} 
    \Return $\perp$ \EndIf
    \If {$ev(f_0, x_0) \neq ev(f_1, x_1)$}
    \Return $\perp$ \EndIf
    \If{$\{x_0,x_1\} \nsubseteq \{0,1\}^{{f_0}.n}$} \Return $\perp$ \EndIf
    $(F, e, d) \leftarrow Gb(1^k, f_b)$; 
    $X \leftarrow En(e, x_b)$
    \Return (F,X, d) 
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{$Game PrvInd_{G,\phi,S}$}
\label{pseudoPSO}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{Garble}{f,x,} 

    \If{$x\notin\{0,1\}^{{f}.n}$}
    \Return $\perp$ \EndIf
    \If {b=1}
    $(F, e, d) \leftarrow Gb(1^k, f)$; 
     $X \leftarrow En(e, x)$
    \Else $ y \leftarrow ev(f, x); (F,X, d) \leftarrow S(1^k, y,\phi(f))$
    \EndIf
    \Return (F,X, d) 
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm

\end{document}
```

I want to show multiple algorithms in single figure having subcaptions to each algorithms on right side as shown in image below :
[image: Desired output]

But what I am getting is this(Shown only for first two algorithms:)

[image: Output]

Is there anyother library I have to use for this

Comment: I can find algorithms, algorithmicx and algorithm2e on ctan, but no algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping those into minipages and not using the float on all?

Answer (score 2):

The following achieves your goal - setting each algorithm inside a `tabular` (to apply the appropriate rules (top and bottom) and then you can use just an `algorithmic` environment to set the pseudocode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,amsmath,amssymb}
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove \EndIf
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{.49\linewidth} @{}}
    \hline
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \Procedure{Garble}{$f_0, f_1, x_0, x_1$}\hfill $\text{Game PrvInd}_{G,\phi}$
        \If{$f(\phi(f0) \neq \phi(f1))$} \Return $\perp$
        \EndIf
        \If{$\text{ev}(f_0, x_0) \neq \text{ev}(f_1, x_1)$} \Return $\perp$
        \EndIf
        \If{$\{x_0,x_1\} \nsubseteq \{0,1\}^{{f_0} \cdot n}$} \Return $\perp$
        \EndIf
        \State $(F, e, d) \leftarrow \text{Gb}(1^k, f_b)$;
        $X \leftarrow \text{En}(e, x_b)$
        \Return $(F, X, d)$
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{.49\linewidth} @{}}
    \hline
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \Procedure{Garble}{$f,x$}\hfill $\text{Game PrvInd}_{G,\phi,S}$
        \If{$x \notin \{0,1\}^{{f} \cdot n}$} \Return $\perp$
        \EndIf
        \If{$b = 1$} $(F, e, d) \leftarrow \text{Gb}(1^k, f)$;
          $X \leftarrow \text{En}(e, x)$
        \Else{} $y \leftarrow \text{ev}(f, x)$; $(F, X, d) \leftarrow S(1^k, y, \phi(f))$
        \EndIf
        \State \Return $(F, X, d)$
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Some games and their definitions.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```